# Using wxString with Google Mock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, wxwidgets, googlemock

Has anyone out there had any luck using Google Mock in conjunction with wxWidgets?  I have a class Foo with setters that take a const reference to wxString in the signature like so:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
    virtual ~Foo();
    void setName(const wxString& name);
};
```

I then proceed to mock Foo like this:

```
class MockFoo : public Foo {
    MOCK_METHOD1(setName, void(const wxString& name));
};
```

My other mocks works just fine but there is something about the wxString parameter that it doesn't like.  When I compile I see the following:

```
C:\gmock-1.6.0\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-internal.h:890: error: conversion from `const wxUniChar' to `long long int' is ambiguous
C:\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx\unichar.h:74: note: candidates are: wxUniChar::operator char() const
C:\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx\unichar.h:75: note:                 wxUniChar::operator unsigned char() const
//more potential candidates from wxUniChar follow after that
```

The jist is that Google Mock cannot determine which operator() function to call since the operator() functions provided by wxUniChar do not map to what Google Mock expects.  I am seeing this error for the 'long long int' and the 'testing::internal::BiggestInt' conversions.

Answer (score 0):

This must be a consequence of using a proxy class, `wxUniCharRef`, as the result type of `wxString::operator[]()` (see the "Traps for the unwary" section of [wxString documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_string.html) for more details), but I'm not sure about where exactly does it come from as there doesn't seem to be any code accessing wxString characters here. What exactly is at the line 890 of `gtest-internal.h`?

Also, you say that you're using a const reference to wxString, but your code doesn't. I don't think it's really relevant for your question but it's confusing to have this discrepancy between the description and the code snippets...

Comment: Sorry for the inconsistency.  I updated the example.  I was able to fix my problem by adding a constructor and various operator= and operator() functions to wxUniChar for the 'long long int' type and building wxWidgets.

Answer (score 0):

The following additions to the wxUniChar header file seemed to work:

```
wxUniChar(long long int c) { m_value = c; }

operator long long int() const { return (long long int)m_value; }

wxUniChar& operator=(long long int c) { m_value = c; return *this; }

bool operator op(long long int c) const { return m_value op (value_type)c; }

wxUniCharRef& operator=(long long int c) { return *this = wxUniChar(c); }

operator long long int() const { return UniChar(); }

bool operator op(long long int c) const { return UniChar() op c; }
```

I plugged these into the appropriate sections of the header file and the compilation error went away.  If I have time later I will work on a patch for wxWidgets with some unit tests if this sounds like a reasonable solution.

Comment: If we really need to allow mixing `wxUniChar` and `long long` in the same expression, then we really need this (and the same for `unsigned long long` too). But I still wonder why is this needed in the first place...

Comment: I believe it is because Google Test is using what it calls the 'BiggestInt' type possible in some of its internal code that performs validation on the Google Mock objects.  It looks like it is long long int or __int64 depending on the platform.